# Resizing Images in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, resize, image-manipulation

I'd like to make a simple VB utility to resize images using vb.net. I am having trouble figuring out what vb class to use to actually manipulate the images. The Image class and the Bitmap class don't work.

Any ideas, hints, tips, tutorial links are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_resize.html) with full details on how to do this.

```
Private Sub btnScale_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnScale.Click
    ' Get the scale factor.
    Dim scale_factor As Single = Single.Parse(txtScale.Text)

    ' Get the source bitmap.
    Dim bm_source As New Bitmap(picSource.Image)

    ' Make a bitmap for the result.
    Dim bm_dest As New Bitmap( _
        CInt(bm_source.Width * scale_factor), _
        CInt(bm_source.Height * scale_factor))

    ' Make a Graphics object for the result Bitmap.
    Dim gr_dest As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm_dest)

    ' Copy the source image into the destination bitmap.
    gr_dest.DrawImage(bm_source, 0, 0, _
        bm_dest.Width + 1, _
        bm_dest.Height + 1)

    ' Display the result.
    picDest.Image = bm_dest
End Sub
```

[Edit]
[One more](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/image_croppingVBNet.aspx) on the similar lines.

Answer (score 30):

You can simply use this one line code to resize your image in visual basic .net

```
Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal InputImage As Image) As Image
        Return New Bitmap(InputImage, New Size(64, 64))
End Function
```

Where;

1. "InputImage" is the image you want to resize.
2. "64 X 64" is the required size you may change it as your needs i.e 32X32 etc.

Comment: Simple and quick. Some side effects will occur regarding the aspect ratio but it can be handled.

Comment: @MohamedNagieb you can calculate aspect ratio using this formula `(original height / original width) x new width = new height`

Answer (score 5):

This will re-size any image using the best quality with support for 32bpp with alpha.  The new image will have the original image centered inside the new one at the original aspect ratio.

```
#Region " ResizeImage "
    Public Overloads Shared Function ResizeImage(SourceImage As Drawing.Image, TargetWidth As Int32, TargetHeight As Int32) As Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim bmSource = New Drawing.Bitmap(SourceImage)

        Return ResizeImage(bmSource, TargetWidth, TargetHeight)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Shared Function ResizeImage(bmSource As Drawing.Bitmap, TargetWidth As Int32, TargetHeight As Int32) As Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim bmDest As New Drawing.Bitmap(TargetWidth, TargetHeight, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        Dim nSourceAspectRatio = bmSource.Width / bmSource.Height
        Dim nDestAspectRatio = bmDest.Width / bmDest.Height

        Dim NewX = 0
        Dim NewY = 0
        Dim NewWidth = bmDest.Width
        Dim NewHeight = bmDest.Height

        If nDestAspectRatio = nSourceAspectRatio Then
            'same ratio
        ElseIf nDestAspectRatio > nSourceAspectRatio Then
            'Source is taller
            NewWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(nSourceAspectRatio * NewHeight))
            NewX = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((bmDest.Width - NewWidth) / 2))
        Else
            'Source is wider
            NewHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((1 / nSourceAspectRatio) * NewWidth))
            NewY = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((bmDest.Height - NewHeight) / 2))
        End If

        Using grDest = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmDest)
            With grDest
                .CompositingQuality = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                .InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                .PixelOffsetMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                .SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
                .CompositingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver

                .DrawImage(bmSource, NewX, NewY, NewWidth, NewHeight)
            End With
        End Using

        Return bmDest
    End Function
#End Region
```

Comment: `Drawing2D.SmoothingMode` doesn't apply here, it is only relevant for 2D vector drawing methods such as `Graphics.DrawLine`

Comment: Be careful with this. The `With grDest` section appeared to ever-so-slightly increase alpha values, only noticeable on iterative processing of the same image with a semi-opaque element to the image. Over time, this became less and less opaque. I commented out the .SmoothingMode part and Changed CompositingMode to SourceCopy. Still testing but one of these two seem to have done it. Afraid I can't give an accurate answer as don't understand GDI that well. Maybe @Carter may be able to help further given his knowledge of GDI.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much VB.NET syntax but here's and idea

```
Dim source As New Bitmap("C:\image.png") 
Dim target As New Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target)
    graphics.DrawImage(source, new Size(48, 48)) 
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically [Muhammad Saqib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22474102/3066563) except two diffs:

1:  Adds **width** and **height** function parameters.

2:  This is a small nuance which can be ignored... Saying **'As Bitmap'**, instead of 'As Image'.  'As Image' does work just fine.  I just prefer to match `Return` types.  See [Image VS Bitmap Class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946926/image-vs-bitmap-class)

```
Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal InputBitmap As Bitmap, width As Integer, height As Integer) As Bitmap
    Return New Bitmap(InputImage, New Size(width, height))
End Function
```

Ex.

```
Dim someimage As New Bitmap("C:\somefile")
someimage = ResizeImage(someimage,800,600)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    Dim k = 0
    Dim l = 0
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(p1.Image)
    Dim om As New Bitmap(p1.Image.Width, p1.Image.Height)
    Dim r, g, b As Byte
    Do While x < bm.Width - 1
        y = 0
        l = 0
        Do While y < bm.Height - 1
            r = 255 - bm.GetPixel(x, y).R
            g = 255 - bm.GetPixel(x, y).G
            b = 255 - bm.GetPixel(x, y).B
            om.SetPixel(k, l, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))
            y += 3
            l += 1
        Loop
        x += 3
        k += 1
    Loop
    p2.Image = om
```