# How can save image with original bit depth?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Dim strFolder = "E:\test\"
        Dim oFile =strFolder & "a.png"
        If oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".png") Or oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".jpg") Or oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".jpeg") Then
            Dim strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(oFile)
            Try
                Dim original As Image = Image.FromFile(oFile)
                ' Calculate the scaled dimensions
                Dim w As Integer = CInt(original.Width * 0.9)
                Dim h As Integer = CInt(original.Height * 0.9)
                Dim encoderParams = New EncoderParameters(1)
                encoderParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8L)

                Dim resized As Image = New Bitmap(original, New Size(w, h))
                Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                resized.Save(memStream, getCodec("image/jpeg"), encoderParams)
                Dim file As New FileStream(strFolder & "905_" & strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                memStream.WriteTo(file)
                file.Close()
                memStream.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End If
    End Sub
  
    Public Function getCodec(getThis) As Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
        Dim output As Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
        Dim codecs As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo() = Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders
        For Each codec As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo In codecs
            If codec.MimeType = getThis Then
                output = codec
            End If
        Next codec
        Return output
    End Function
```

Bit Depth of Original file: 8 bit

[image]

But after resize, it is 24 bit:

[image]

How can save image with original bit depth?

Comment: Maybe you can use part of this answer, but use a Bitmap constructor with PixelFormat parameter for bm_dest? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144618/9173710
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144627/9173710

Comment: If you're saving as .png, why are you using jpeg encoder?

Comment: Most native encoders don't support that kind of color depth. In relation to the JPEG encoder, it doesn't even support the `ColorDepth` parameter, it's just ignored. You also cannot use the Graphics object to draw 8bpp images. If you need to extend the support for image conversions, you need third-party libraries, as [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)