# Image vs BitmapImage vs Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I was wondering what the difference is between `Image`, `Bitmap` and `BitmapImage` in WPF & C#.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946926/image-vs-bitmap-class may be of some help

Comment: This has already been answered but this link may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16080211/1319753

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is a base abstract class representing images in GDI+. [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is a concrete implementation of this base class.

[BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) is a way to represent an image in a vector based GUI engine like WPF and Silverlight. Contrary to a `Bitmap`, it is not based on GDI+. It is based on the [Windows Imaging Component](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=32).

There are ways to [load a `BitmapImage` from a `Bitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap).

Comment: What would be the best for simply reading some pixel data from a PNG - GDI+ or Imaging way?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov,  Windows Imaging Component URL is no longer a valid URL. I think you need to update it.

Answer (score 13):

**WinForms/GDI+** uses the abstract class `System.Drawing.Image` and its implementation `Bitmap`.

**WPF** uses the abstract class System.Windows.Media.`ImageSource` (and `BitmapSource`) and its implementation `BitmapImage`.

WPF also has a control named `Image`, which is a `FrameworkElement` that contains and displays an `ImageSource`.

It took me a while to untangle that mess of terminology...

Comment: I am very new to all these topics - C#, WPF, and WinForms. It is my understanding that WPF is potentially faster than WinForms because it accesses hardware for rendering, whereas WinForms uses GDI/GDI+. When using WPF, as long as you are using the FrameworkElement version of the Image class, it should be hardware accelerated, correct? Whereas if you were to use the System.Drawing.Image class within WPF, it would be GDI/GDI+? I had been trying to avoid the Image class in WPF because I thought it was all GDI/GDI+, not realizing that WPF had it's own Image class that was, I assume, faster?