# Differences between Image and BitmapImage with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

In `Image`'s asdoc, we can see :

> Flex also includes the BitmapImage class. This class is used for embedding images into skins and FXG components

but we can also use `Image` in skins and use `@Embed` with `Image`...

Therefore, where and when should I use `Image` or `BitmapImage` please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Image` is a skinnable class that wraps `BitmapImage`. As such BitmapImage is more lightweight, but Image has more features. So the question when to use which boils down to this:
if the features of BitmapImage suffice, use that; otherwise use Image. Especially in mobile environments try to favor the use of BitmapImage.

**Now what features does Image add exactly?**

- Image extends SkinnableComponent: this means you can assign your images a skin with a border or a dropshadow or whatever you like consistently throughout your application.
- It also provides a progress indicator which can be displayed while the image is loading.
- One more feature is the possibility to [queue the loading of multiple images](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-8000.html#WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-7ffc).

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation. In my case, I will use it inside basic skin so I will use BitmapImage (and Embed).