# .net System.Drawing namespace - what are the differences between bitmap, image and graphics?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to image manipulation in .net and a little bit confused about the available classes in the framework.

As far as I know the main classes are

- Bitmap
- Image
- Graphics

Could someone explain which class is used for what?

Comment: Go to MSDN.com and read a bit about each class. Post question if you still have any confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is a base abstract class representing a raster image. [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is one implementation of this abstract class based on GDI+. [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) is what allows you to draw shapes in GDI+. It represents a drawing surface.

Answer (score 2):

About Bitmap and Image:
Image is an abstract class, Bitmap is the implementation of this class. The Bitmap class contains 12 constructors that construct the Bitmap object from different parameters. It can construct the Bitmap from another bitmap, and the string path of the image.

The class Graphics is to work with the Bitmap objects (GDI+), you can draw on a bitmap, save it, rotate it every kind of thing you want.

for more information you should look at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

`Image` is the abstract base class of `Bitmap` and `Graphics` seems to be a GDI+ wraper.

Answer (score 0):

For difference between Bitmap and Image you can have a look here [Image vs Bitmap class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946926/image-vs-bitmap-class).

Graphics, instead is an implementation of access to OS Device Context.
For rendering a "stuff" on the screen (texts, images, video, animations...)

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface