# What is the difference between System.Drawing.Image and System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap, drawing

I am confused what's the different between `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Can someone explain the major difference between those two types ?

And Why to use System.Drawing.Bitmap instead of System.Drawing.Image ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946926/image-vs-bitmap-class 

please check this too...

Comment: From OO perspective, Bitmap `is an` Image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Bitmap` inherits from `Image`:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap : System.Drawing.Image
{ }
```

`Image` is an abstract class, this means:

> The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation.

`Bitmap` is a sealed class, this means:

> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.

See the following:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename); // Works
Image img = new Image(); // The compiler says: "Cannot access internal constructer 'Image' here.
```

This is because `Image` is not meant to be used this way.
It just provides functionality for the `Bitmap` class.

Thus use `Bitmap` when dealing with pixelated images, like jpeg, png, bmp, etc.

If you expect no specific type of image in your method and the methods of `Image` are sufficient, use the more general `Image` as parameter type. This method will then accept other classes inheriting from `Image` as well, for example `Metafile`.

Comment: If I might add -- don't be afraid to pass a variable of type `Bitmap` to a function that takes `Image` as a parameter...  since `Bitmap` is an `Image`, it will accept it. For example, `g.DrawImage(mybitmap, 0, 0)` is valid with `mybitmap` of type `Bitmap` (here, `g` is of type `Graphics`, and `DrawImage` takes `Image` as a parameter).

Comment: @CPerkins You are right. Thanks for pointing this out! I adjusted my post, feel free to improve it.

Comment: Is there a benefit of using, for example, `Image.FromFile()` directly? I have seen it used many times to only be cast to bitmap in the next step.

Comment: From the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,e328c776c1ca78db,references
It seems it could also return a `Metafile` object. Then a cast to `Bitmap` would fail. But you usually know beforehand which type of object is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Am not sure what you mean difference?

`System.Drawing.Image` is the base class for `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

`System.Drawing.Image` is abstract class as well, so you can't create instance of it. You'll have to create instance of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` only.

`Image.FromFile`, Image.BlahBlah... returns you instance of `Bitmap` only.

Answer (score 3):

As the MSDN documentation clearly states about `System.Drawing.Image`:

> An abstract base class that provides functionality for the Bitmap and Metafile descended classes.

So you cannot compare them. The `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class is a concrete implementation of the abstract `System.Drawing.Image` class.

Answer (score 1):

Image is a base abstract class representing a raster image. Bitmap is one implementation of this abstract class based on GDI+.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path); // Works
```

So, although you can't create an object of type "Image", you can still use its methods. Note however the cast to Bitmap.