# Find image with Highest Resolution from a list of images

Tags: c#, bitmap

There is a List of file paths available and stored like below

```
List<string> file_list = new List<string>(); // list of file paths
```

How can i find the image with Highest resolution  [ Width or Height ] Usually all images are uniform in width and height example: 300*300 / 1200 *1200 etc

Current approach

```
foreach (string file in filesList)
{
    Bitmap image= new Bitmap(file);
    image.width && image.Height  and compare the values 
}
```

Is any easiest/ straight forward approach ?

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the `Bitmap` when you're done. I don't think there's likely to be a better approach, especially not when you have to dispose of them.

Comment: I would write `foreach (string file in filesList)
{
    using (Bitmap image= new Bitmap(file)) dictionary.Add(file, image.width) }` with a `Dictionary<string, int>` Then you can inspect the values..

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is best performing implementation I know of

```
string largestFile = null;
int largestSize = 0;

foreach (var file in file_list)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream, false, false))
        {
            if (image.Width > largestSize)
            {
                largestFile = file;
                largestSize = image.Width;
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The largest file is: " + largestFile);
```

Comment: Any advantage Bitmap  over Image  FromStream?

Comment: @Sebastian You could use Bitmap.FromStream as well, with no recognizable effect, the Bitmap class is an implementation of the Image class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946926/image-vs-bitmap-class). The performance change is mainly from using streams as explained [here](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2012/02/28/fastest-way-to-read-dimensions-from-a-picture-image-file-in-c/)

Comment: This will not detect images of the same (maximum) size.

Comment: @TaW OP's question does not mention that requirement

Comment: Just saying. My comment solved this easily. so the answer is a step back, imo.

Comment: `New Bitmap(filename)` will just create the stream internally. I don't see any point in making the `FileStream` explicitly; it'll get closed and disposed with the bitmap anyway.